# Failed to connect to shadowsocks client

Tags: networking, socks

I've configured shadowsocks system by running ss-server on VPS and ss-local on my client machine.
Then I made a simple SOCKS5 client which connects to ss-local and resolve SOCKS request using C.
All work well, when I run ss-tunnel instead of ss-local, my SOCKS5 client can't connect to ss-tunnel.

TCP connection terminates as soon as it established.
I'm not sure what is the proper reason.

```
ss-tunnel -c config.json -L <destaddr:port>
```

But it does when I run ss-local instead.

```
ss-local -c config.json
```

Below is my config file.

```
{
    "server":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "server_port":443,
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":10800,
    "password":"xxxxxxxxxx",
    "timeout":60,
    "method":"chacha20-ietf-poly1305",
    "workers":8,
    "plugin":"obfs-local",
    "plugin_opts":"obfs=tls;obfs-host=www.google.com"
}
```

Is there any difference between protocols of ss-local and ss-tunnel? I know it's false, but anyway can't get it how they go wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ss-tunnel establishes a complete tunnel with ss-server, all traffic to ss-tunnel is directly relayed to ss-server without any SOCKS request/resolve processes.
After I've removed SOCKS handshake in my client program, it worked properly.